# Removing FB apps from user settings ideally should restrict my Access tokens but it DOESNOT

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

My product users are using the Facebbok apps for authorisation and generating Keys and tokens.
When I remove the app, my users are still able to connect and fetch the posts from facebook. How is that..? The old tokens should nto work as I assumed , but they are still working.. Does it takes time to reflect.?

Please help me..:)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  If the problem is that after you remove your app from Facebook that users can still see data your app posted to Facebook, I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made a post to facebook through one of your apps, you can also delete that post from the same app. You need to get the post ID (it will be returned when you sucessfully do a post in the first place). Then issue a "DELETE" request. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

If you have deleted the app, or the user posted the items themselves (through a share dialog), or you can't find the Post ID, or the user has revoked the "publish_stream" permission, then the post is there to stay.

Answer (score 0):

When one of your users removes an app from the privacy settings interface[image: privacy settings interface], the app's access tokens are invalidated. This should be immediate.

However, nothing stops you from going back into the app and authorising it again, and content produced by that app will still be visible on your Timeline. The other answer here shows how you can delete feed stories made by the app, if you want to do that for some reason.

Also, check your users aren't either removing stories by the app from their feed, or hiding the app from Timeline, neither of which removes their ability to use the app or would invalidate the tokens.

You can also programmatically remove the app from a user's account with a `HTTP DELETE` request to `/USER_ID/permissions` using the user's access token or an app access token